# Is it possible to calculate only a part of SHA512 hash? (C#)

Tags: brute-force, sha512

I'm trying to solve a keygenme task. I found that there is a `ulong` value stored as a `string`. Hash is calculated using `SHA512Managed` and only 16 bytes of a 128 byte result matters. I need to find such a `ulong` value stored as a `string` that gives hash that has 16 specific bytes. 
As I understand, SHA algorithm can't be reversed, thus the only possible solution is a brute-force approach. There are 18,446,744,073,709,551,616 possible ulong values which is quite a lot. 
So, the question is "is it possible to calculate only 16 bytes oh hash in order to decrease calculation time?".
P.S. If you know another way to solve my task, please tell me. Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, it is not. The algorithm rotates values so you cannot leave any part of it out when calculating.

Theoretically you could leave a small part out of the last round but that wouldn't have any real meaning to the time spent brute forcing.